# Trying to load local PDF file in UIWebView crashing

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

This seems like such a simple piece of code that keeps crashing on me.  It's able to find the file and I see it in the logs, but it crashes every time at the webview.loadRequest request line:

```
let kHelpFile = "DB_Help_Doc"

webView.delegate = self

webView.scalesPageToFit = true

self.view.addSubview(webView)


Scripts.log("WebViewVC >> URL is \(kHelpFile)")

if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(kHelpFile, withExtension: "pdf") {

    Scripts.log("BUNDLE FOUND")
    Scripts.log("URL = \(url)")
    Scripts.log("PATH = \(url.path)")

    req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url.path!))

    self.webView.loadRequest(req)

}
else {

    Scripts.log("BUNDLE NOT FOUND")

}
```

**This is the exception**

> libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw:
>   ->  0x10e077c6b <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
>       0x10e077c6c <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
>       0x10e077c6f <+4>:   pushq  %r15
>       0x10e077c71 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
>       0x10e077c73 <+8>:   pushq  %r12
>       0x10e077c75 <+10>:  pushq  %rbx
>       0x10e077c76 <+11>:  movq   %rdx, %r14
>       0x10e077c79 <+14>:  movq   %rsi, %r15
>       0x10e077c7c <+17>:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
>       0x10e077c7f <+20>:  callq  0x10e07787d               ; __cxa_get_globals
>       0x10e077c84 <+25>:  movq   %rax, %r12
>       0x10e077c87 <+28>:  callq  0x10e078220               ; std::get_unexpected()
>       0x10e077c8c <+33>:  movq   %rax, -0x60(%rbx)
>       0x10e077c90 <+37>:  callq  0x10e078258               ; std::get_terminate()
>       0x10e077c95 <+42>:  movq   %rax, -0x58(%rbx)
>       0x10e077c99 <+46>:  movq   %r15, -0x70(%rbx)
>       0x10e077c9d <+50>:  movq   %r14, -0x68(%rbx)
>       0x10e077ca1 <+54>:  leaq   -0x20(%rbx), %r14
>       0x10e077ca5 <+58>:  movabsq $0x434c4e47432b2b00, %rax
>       0x10e077caf <+68>:  movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbx)
>       0x10e077cb3 <+72>:  movq   $0x1, -0x78(%rbx)
>       0x10e077cbb <+80>:  incl   0x8(%r12)
>       0x10e077cc0 <+85>:  leaq   0x1d(%rip), %rax          ; __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
>       0x10e077cc7 <+92>:  movq   %rax, -0x18(%rbx)
>       0x10e077ccb <+96>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
>       0x10e077cce <+99>:  callq  0x10e07ab3c               ; symbol stub for: _Unwind_RaiseException
>       0x10e077cd3 <+104>: movq   %r14, %rdi
>       0x10e077cd6 <+107>: callq  0x10e077d08               ; __cxa_begin_catch
>       0x10e077cdb <+112>: movq   -0x58(%rbx), %rdi
>       0x10e077cdf <+116>: callq  0x10e078266               ; std::__terminate(void (*)())

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Looks like you have added something else. What is the name of the exception? Check your XCode console.

Comment: var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url.path!)!) chnage and try this

Comment: That's what os frustrating, the console just shows this after crashing, not much of a help: 140689594808888

(lldb)